# In Django, how do I make sure that my forms keep its initial value after being submitted but returned to the template due to an error?

Tags: python, django, templates, forms

Let's say someone submits a form.
It doesn't pass is_valid(), and I return them back to the template.

How do I display the form fields again, without having the person retype their stuff?

I prefer not to use the { initial: } option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your view like so:

```
def showForm(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do stuff on success, like redirection
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render_to_response(...,
                              {"form" : form})
    # then in the template, use {{ form.as_table }}, for example
```

Comment: This is the standard way to do it: fill your form with POST data. If valid, save and redirect, if not, render the template with the form as it is.